# TortoiseSVN remote and local url automatic change

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a subversion server set up at home with my Raspberry Pi. Im using a dynamic DNS to acces it from outside, so there is the problem.

When I'm home, in order to acces the repostory, I have to use http://192.168.1.XX/svn/MyRepostory but when im not home i have to use the url providfed by the DynDNS service.

The problem is that TortoiseSVN only acceptes one url to update/commit the repostory so if i set it up with the local one whenever im outside it doesent work and viceversa.

Is there any way to solve this?
Maybe some kind of backup url so if first one fails it tries whith the other?

Comment: any ideas.....?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to solve this? Maybe some kind of backup url so if
>   first one fails it tries whith the other?

The correct solution would be to configure your server properly and use the same URL to the repository when accessing it from your LAN and from WAN.

If it's not possible in your case by some reason, run [`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) command to relocate your working copies from one URL to another. See [TortoiseSVN Manual | Relocating a working copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html).